# WebService Connection, HTTPS UserName, password authentication fails with Anonymous error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

A customer of us has adjusted their security on the webservices.
We normally called an ASMX webservice with no authentication. Now they have put a certificate on the HTTPS and added a Windows user for us to authenticate.

Regardless of what properties I'm setting and how I'm always getting:
"`The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM,Basic realm="www.domain.com"'.`"

If I input the link inside a browser, then the browser asks for the username and password and I'm able to see the WSDL.
But if I remove the ?WSDL then it indicates that I'm not authorized.

Did somebody encountered such behavior and knows how to make sure the service is properly setup?

I have tried a number of possible combinations with adjusting the Transport/Message credentials to other values but it doesn't matter, it still gives me that error.

Comment: have you tried disabling anonymous authentication is IIS?

Comment: We used to connect anonymously. But now the third party has setup tighter security.
We do not have access to the IIS en we used to be able to connect without problems. 
So for me it seems a problem at their side.

Comment: To be clear on the connection:
I use a BasicHttpBinding

with
<binding name="basicSynergyBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

And in the code I set the 
ClientCredentials.UserName
 and 
ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential